# Test not passing but manual testing works fine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara, factory-bot

I am running a test that is failing with the following message:

```
1) User pages profile page 
 Failure/Error: before { visit user_path(user) }
 ActionView::Template::Error:
   undefined local variable or method `new_key_path' for #<#<Class:0x007fa775c4bc50>:0x007fa775c48910>
 # ./app/views/users/show.html.erb:21:in `_app_views_users_show_html_erb__4517315841728073114_70178605538620'
 # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:58:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

However, when I look at the page and follow the link manually, it works as it should. This is the test's code:

```
describe "profile page" do
let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
# let!(:key1) { FactoryGirl.create(:key) }
let!(:key1) { user.keys.build(name: "test", description: "test description", is_public: false) }

before { visit user_path(user) }

it { should have_content(user.name) }
it { should have_title(user.name) }

describe "keys" do
  it { should have_content(key1.name) }
  it { should have_content(key1.description) }
end
end
```

The 'show' page in question is:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="span12">
<% if @user.keys.any? %>
  <h3>My Keys (<%= @user.keys.count %>)</h3>
  <ol class="microposts">
    <%= render @keys %>
  </ol>
  <%= will_paginate @keys %>
<% end %>
<%= link_to "New Key", new_key_path, 
                            class: "btn btn-large" %>
```

Any idea what is causing the test to fail?

On a somewhat unrelated note, you might have noticed that I am not using a factory for :key1. This is because I kept getting this error when using it:

```
1) User pages profile page 
 Failure/Error: let!(:key1) { FactoryGirl.create(:key) }
 ArgumentError:
   Factory not registered: key
 # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:55:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Despite my factories.rb file having :key in it:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
factory :user do
sequence(:name)  { |n| "Person #{n}" }
sequence(:email) { |n| "person_#{n}@example.com"}   
password "foobar"
password_confirmation "foobar"

factory :admin do
  admin true
end
end

factory :key do
  name "Test Key"
  description "This is a test key"
  is_public false
  user
end
end
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

**EDIT: Added routes**

```
SampleApp::Application.routes.draw do
get "keys/new"
resources :users
resources :sessions,    only: [:new, :create, :destroy]
resources :keys,        only: [:index, :new, :destroy, :create]

root to: 'static_pages#home'
match '/signup',  to: 'users#new',            via: 'get'
match '/signin',  to: 'sessions#new',         via: 'get'
match '/signout', to: 'sessions#destroy',     via: 'delete'
match '/help',    to: 'static_pages#help',    via: 'get'
match '/about',   to: 'static_pages#about',   via: 'get'
match '/contact', to: 'static_pages#contact', via: 'get'
```

end

**Result of rake routes:**

```
Prefix Verb   URI Pattern               Controller#Action
keys_new GET    /keys/new(.:format)       keys#new
  users GET    /users(.:format)          users#index
        POST   /users(.:format)          users#create
new_user GET    /users/new(.:format)      users#new
edit_user GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format) users#edit
   user GET    /users/:id(.:format)      users#show
        PATCH  /users/:id(.:format)      users#update
        PUT    /users/:id(.:format)      users#update
        DELETE /users/:id(.:format)      users#destroy
sessions POST   /sessions(.:format)       sessions#create
new_session GET    /sessions/new(.:format)   sessions#new
session DELETE /sessions/:id(.:format)   sessions#destroy
   keys GET    /keys(.:format)           keys#index
        POST   /keys(.:format)           keys#create
new_key GET    /keys/new(.:format)       keys#new
    key DELETE /keys/:id(.:format)       keys#destroy
   root GET    /                         static_pages#home
 signup GET    /signup(.:format)         users#new
 signin GET    /signin(.:format)         sessions#new
signout DELETE /signout(.:format)        sessions#destroy
   help GET    /help(.:format)           static_pages#help
  about GET    /about(.:format)          static_pages#about
contact GET    /contact(.:format)        static_pages#contact
```

Comment: Would you share your `config/routes.rb` file and the result of `rake routes`?  As for the `FactoryGirl` problem, where is your `factories.rb` file located? Also, are you running `spork` or any background test process?

Comment: Oh, and in case it wasn't clear, the error is from the call to `new_key_path` in your view. It's failing because an associated route hasn't been defined for it.

Comment: What does your routes.rb file look like?

Comment: @PeterAlfvin, I've added the my config/routes.rb file and the the result of rake routes. To answer your other question, yes, I am running spork and I am running my tests directly in Sublime Text 2. To clarify another point, my manual are tests are working completely, including creating new keys directly from the user/show page. Thanks!

Comment: @AmyHua, added the routes.rb file, thanks

Comment: @PeterAlfvin, I reset my spork server and the tests are now passing. Very strange, but thanks for your help. Any idea what may have caused that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that it worked after restarting spork, you've likely encountered one of the cases where spork does not pick up changes you've made.  See [Spork/Autotest not picking up changes automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7240990/spork-autotest-not-picking-up-changes-automatically) for discussion and the highest voted answer for workarounds.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably able to see the page when you manually go to it in your browser, but upon visiting "New Key", you should have problems seeing the "New Key" page, because `new_key_path` doesn't exist.

If `key` is meant to be a child of `user`, then it should be `new_user_key_path` instead, assuming your routes are properly set up:

```
resources :users do
  resources :keys
  ...
end
```

Try using `new_user_key_path` instead of:

```
<%= link_to "New Key", new_key_path, 
                        class: "btn btn-large" %>
```

In your show.

Otherwise, if `key` is not meant to be a child of `user`,

Your factory for key1 isn't registering because you need to define a separate FactoryGirl factory for it.

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :key do
    ...
  end
end
```

It is currently being treated as a child of `user`. If you properly indent your code, you'll realize you left it out:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    sequence(:name)  { |n| "Person #{n}" }
    sequence(:email) { |n| "person_#{n}@example.com"}   
    password "foobar"
    password_confirmation "foobar"

    factory :admin do
      admin true
    end
  end

  # Missing end

  # Missing FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :key do
    name "Test Key"
    description "This is a test key"
    is_public false
    user
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks @amyhua, I've added the routes to my code above. To clarify, I am able to access the New Key page directly from my browser and have no problem adding new keys from the user/show page. Thanks again!

Comment: I reset my spork server and the tests are now passing. Very strange, but thanks for your help. Any idea what may have caused that?